# Custom parameter annotation in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a controller which retrieves the userId from the session making the request:

```
@GetMapping("/transactions-per-category/{type}")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getTransactionsPerCategory(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable CashflowType type) {
        // Retrieve userId
        Claims claims = jwtUtil.resolveClaims(request);
        Integer userId = (Integer) claims.get("id");
    
        
        try {
            Collection<TransactionsPerCategory> chartData = cashflowService.getCashflowTransactionsPerCategory(userId, type);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(chartData);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }
    }
```

Because almost all methods have

```
Claims claims = jwtUtil.resolveClaims(request);
Integer userId = (Integer) claims.get("id");
```

I want to write it shorter. I tried implementing a custom parameter annotation which would put the value of the userId at runtime.

```
@GetMapping("/revenue-expense-monthly")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getRevenueAndExpensesMonthly(HttpServletRequest request, @ExtractUserIdFromToken Integer userId) {
        System.out.println("ID " + userId);
        try {
            Collection<RevenueAndExpensesMonthly> chartData = cashflowService.getCashflowRevenueAndExpensesMonthly(userId);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(chartData);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }
    }
```

To do this I first made a new Java-config class:

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.EnableSpringConfigured;

@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

}
```

These are some dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Then I made an interface for the annotation:

```
package com.example.demo.auth;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ExtractUserIdFromToken {

}
```

With the following implementation:

```
package com.example.demo.auth;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Component
@Aspect
public class ExtractUserIdAspect {
    
     @Autowired
     private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
     
    @Around(value = "@annotation(extractUserIdFromToken)")
    public void aroundMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint, ExtractUserIdFromToken extractUserIdFromToken) {
     
        System.out.println("Test");
     
        for (Object arg : joinPoint.getArgs()) {
            if (arg instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg;
                Authentication authentication = (Authentication) request.getUserPrincipal();
                if (authentication != null) {
                    Claims claims = jwtUtil.resolveClaims(request);
                    Integer userId = (Integer) claims.get("id");
                    for (int i = 0; i < joinPoint.getArgs().length; i++) {
                        if (joinPoint.getArgs()[i] != null && joinPoint.getArgs()[i].getClass() == Integer.class) {
                            joinPoint.getArgs()[i] = userId;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
@GetMapping("/revenue-expense-monthly")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getRevenueAndExpensesMonthly(HttpServletRequest request, @ExtractUserIdFromToken Integer userId) {
        System.out.println("ID " + userId);
        try {
            <RevenueAndExpensesMonthly> chartData = cashflowService.getCashflowRevenueAndExpensesMonthly(userId);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(chartData);
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }
    }
```

Does not even execute the `aroundMethod` (Test is not printed) and userId remains null.